# Apache-Cordova Update to 4.1.1 or Higher for Google Play Store App But its

Tags: android, cordova, store, phonegap, playback

I am getting the below error.

> Please upgrade your app(s) as soon as possible and increment the
>   version number of the upgraded APK. Vulnerability APK Version(s)
>   Apache Cordova
>
> The vulnerabilities were fixed in Apache Cordova v.4.1.1 or higher.
>
> You can find information about how to upgrade in this Google Help
>   Center article.   11
>
> Best,
>
> The Google Play Team

I tried all possible way. I updated to 7.0.0 but still it's not working.

For Cordova platform ls:

```
   Installed platforms: android 7.0.0 Available platforms: browser > ~5.0.1 ios ~4.5.4 osx ~4.0.1 windows ~5.0.0 www ^3.12.0
```

How can I solve above error?

Answer (score 1):

The message says that you have an app in the store that has a cordova below version 4.1.1, the thing you have to do is upgrade cordova on your pc, build the app again with your signing key and then upload this to the play store. They gonna check it and everything should be fine.

Comment: Yes i updated but its now changed all latest library and its not compatible with old code i change but , now i got error related java.lang.ClassCastException: com.simCard.web.WebCall$1 cannot be cast to org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebChromeClient